# INSERT table names using SELECT statement in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-connector

In MySQL, I know I can list the tables in a database with:

```
SHOW TABLES
```

But I want to insert a table name into a specified table, for example:

```
INSERT INTO dataset_names (dataset)
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = '%s';
```

But when I execute the above statement, the dataset_names table does not get updated.
I created the master table using:

```
CREATE TABLE dataset_names (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, dataset text);
```

Here is the python code.

```
    dataset_name_query = """
                        INSERT INTO dataset_names (dataset) values(
                        SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
                        WHERE table_schema = '%s');
                        """% (tablename)
    
    csv_obj.read()
    csv_obj.create()
    cursor = createConnection()
    #Cursor executing the dataset insert into master table query
    cursor.execute(dataset_name_query)
    closeCursor(cursor)
```

Comment: `%s` shouldn't be in quotes. That prevents `cursor.execute()` from performing parameter substitution.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I made that change just now, but still no luck. It executes with no errors but still doesn't update.

Comment: Please post the Python code.

Comment: @Barmar I have added the python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table_names(name) (SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='database_name')
```

Here the order on insert values and select values must match;

Comment: There's only one column, how can the order not match?

Comment: @KrishnaAcharya this didn't help.

Comment: i have updated this will sure will help. also plz remove negative vote

Comment: do not place values in your query.

Comment: You don't need parentheses around the `SELECT` query, it works without them.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a prepared statement, not string formatting. You also need to call `connection.commit()` to make the changes permanent; replace `connection` with the name of your connection variable (it's not shown in your example code).

```
dataset_name_query = """
    INSERT INTO dataset_names (dataset)
    SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = %s;
    """

cursor = createConnection()
#Cursor executing the dataset insert into master table query
cursor.execute(dataset_name_query, [tablename])
connection.commit()
closeCursor(cursor)
```

Comment: I ran this but, still it runs with no erros. closeCursor is a function I made for closing the cursor. MYSQL connector doesn't have the cursor.commit() attribute is the error I receive. I am using flask and MYSQL connector. @Barmar

Comment: Then you need to use `connection.commit()` with your correct connection variable.

Answer (score -2):

You are use wrong syntax to insert data in a table, you forgot to use 'values' keyword before providing values.
Your command should be something like this -

```
INSERT INTO dataset_names (dataset) values(
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = '%s');
```

This should work.

Comment: His syntax is fine. You can use a `SELECT` statement as the source without using `VALUES`.

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: I did that but after doing so, I get a MYSQL syntax error.
@Hemant